# Windows 10 Kiosk Mode in Edge blank screen after inactivity

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, kiosk

I have setup a Windows 10 kiosk where Edge goes to a predefined website.  When I was configuring it, I had left it in my office and every day it seemed to be fine.  Now that I deployed it, I find several hours of inactivity, when one moves the mouse for example to turn off the screensaver/blank screen, the website is all whie with a cursor blinking.

The only way through this is <kbd>control</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>del</kbd> and then invoke the <kbd>enter</kbd> immediately afterwards, essentially to force a sign out, sign in.  Thereby the kiosk website reloads as normal.

I don't think anything has changed since being placed in the lobby.  Is there anything that can cause this behaviour?  The computer doesn't sleep, doesn't hibernate.  It just has a screensaver that goes off after five minutes, and the monitor turns off after an hour.  Sometime there after, when going back to it, Edge craps out.

Comment: Have you set up [assigned access](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/microsoft-edge-kiosk-mode-deploy)?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't think of the term but yes that is what I did.  It is a domain computer with a local user account in assigned access.

Comment: If you did replace "blue screen" with blank screen for OS errors, the computer (or edge) might have crashed. Check in the Event Viewer. You could also [enable logging for kiosk issues](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-pt/windows/configuration/kiosk-prepare#enable-logging).

Comment: It seems to look like the website without any of the text or graphics as the cursor is positioned about where the login prompt would be.

Comment: Check for more info, as there's not enough to go on.

Answer (score 0):

I will post this as an answer because it seemed to have worked.  I thought I saw another answer come through but I don't see it here, but anyway, I went into the advanced power settings control panel and saw sleep/monitor was still marked off after x minutes, even though the main power settings didn't show any such thing.

I also found there were video driver updates.

I left it on all day and saw that only the screen saver was on, instead of the blanked out screen.  When I woke up the screen saver, the kiosk website loaded up.

I won't accept my own answer until I verify this is still working Monday.